# How do I remove a row from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code removes the row if it contains an empty cell in the 3rd column.
It makes use of Jquery's fadeOut-method for a nice effect.
Thing is that I can't get the code working without the faeOut method.

I tried `$(this).remove();` but that does not work.

```js
function TT(){
  var A = 3;
  $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(' + A + ')').each(function(index){
    var cellValue = $("#tbl tr:eq(" + index + ") td:eq(" + A + ")").text();
    if (cellValue.length === 0){
      $(this).parents('tr').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
table {
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 95%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl'>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>E1</td>
    <td>F1</td>
    <td>G1</td>
    <td>H1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E2</td>
    <td>F2</td>
    <td>G2</td>
    <td>H2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>E3</td>
    <td>F3</td>
    <td>G3</td>
    <td>H3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A4</td>
    <td>B4</td>
    <td>C4</td>
    <td>D4</td>
    <td>E4</td>
    <td>F4</td>
    <td>G4</td>
    <td>H4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A5</td>
    <td>B5</td>
    <td>C5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E5</td>
    <td>F5</td>
    <td>G5</td>
    <td>H5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A6</td>
    <td>B6</td>
    <td>C6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E6</td>
    <td>F6</td>
    <td>G6</td>
    <td>H6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A7</td>
    <td>B7</td>
    <td>C7</td>
    <td>D7</td>
    <td>E7</td>
    <td>F7</td>
    <td>G7</td>
    <td>H7</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A8</td>
    <td>B8</td>
    <td>C8</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E8</td>
    <td>F8</td>
    <td>G8</td>
    <td>H8</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A9</td>
    <td>B9</td>
    <td>C9</td>
    <td>D9</td>
    <td>E9</td>
    <td>F9</td>
    <td>G9</td>
    <td>H9</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A10</td>
    <td>B10</td>
    <td>C10</td>
    <td>D10</td>
    <td>E10</td>
    <td>F10</td>
    <td>G10</td>
    <td>H10</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A11</td>
    <td>B11</td>
    <td>C11</td>
    <td>D11</td>
    <td>E11</td>
    <td>F11</td>
    <td>G11</td>
    <td>H11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
 <button type="button" onclick="TT()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: You are talking about row not a column, so I edited the question's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple times you are querying “table” .which is not required. Only the first loop to iterate through all 3rd column elements is sufficient to find out if the cell is empty and to remove the complete row.

```js
function TT(){
  var A = 4;
  $('table tbody tr td:nth-child(' + A + ')')
    .each(function(index){
    if($(this).text()=="" )  {$(this).parent().remove();}
  });
 }
```

```css
table {
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 95%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl'>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>E1</td>
    <td>F1</td>
    <td>G1</td>
    <td>H1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E2</td>
    <td>F2</td>
    <td>G2</td>
    <td>H2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>E3</td>
    <td>F3</td>
    <td>G3</td>
    <td>H3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A4</td>
    <td>B4</td>
    <td>C4</td>
    <td>D4</td>
    <td>E4</td>
    <td>F4</td>
    <td>G4</td>
    <td>H4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A5</td>
    <td>B5</td>
    <td>C5</td>
    <td>D5</td>
    <td>E5</td>
    <td>F5</td>
    <td>G5</td>
    <td>H5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A6</td>
    <td>B6</td>
    <td>C6</td>
    <td>D6</td>
    <td>E6</td>
    <td>F6</td>
    <td>G6</td>
    <td>H6</td>
  </tr>
 


</table>
</br>
 <button type="button" onclick="TT()">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `.each()` you can just use `.filter()`

```js
function TT(){
  var A = 3;
  $('table tbody tr').filter(function(){
    return $('td:eq('+ A +')' , this).text() == ''; // good to use `.text().trim()` to avoid any white-spaces
  }).remove();
}
```

```css
table {
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 95%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tbl'>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>E1</td>
    <td>F1</td>
    <td>G1</td>
    <td>H1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E2</td>
    <td>F2</td>
    <td>G2</td>
    <td>H2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>D3</td>
    <td>E3</td>
    <td>F3</td>
    <td>G3</td>
    <td>H3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A4</td>
    <td>B4</td>
    <td>C4</td>
    <td>D4</td>
    <td>E4</td>
    <td>F4</td>
    <td>G4</td>
    <td>H4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A5</td>
    <td>B5</td>
    <td>C5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E5</td>
    <td>F5</td>
    <td>G5</td>
    <td>H5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A6</td>
    <td>B6</td>
    <td>C6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E6</td>
    <td>F6</td>
    <td>G6</td>
    <td>H6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A7</td>
    <td>B7</td>
    <td>C7</td>
    <td>D7</td>
    <td>E7</td>
    <td>F7</td>
    <td>G7</td>
    <td>H7</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A8</td>
    <td>B8</td>
    <td>C8</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E8</td>
    <td>F8</td>
    <td>G8</td>
    <td>H8</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A9</td>
    <td>B9</td>
    <td>C9</td>
    <td>D9</td>
    <td>E9</td>
    <td>F9</td>
    <td>G9</td>
    <td>H9</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A10</td>
    <td>B10</td>
    <td>C10</td>
    <td>D10</td>
    <td>E10</td>
    <td>F10</td>
    <td>G10</td>
    <td>H10</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>A11</td>
    <td>B11</td>
    <td>C11</td>
    <td>D11</td>
    <td>E11</td>
    <td>F11</td>
    <td>G11</td>
    <td>H11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
 <button type="button" onclick="TT()">Click Me!</button>
```

> **Note:** `parent()` , `parents()` , `closest()` all of those should work if you start from `<td>` .. but for me a simple thing is to start
>   from the `<tr>` not from the `<td>`

**Another note:** `:nth-child(index)` index starts from 1 .. and `:eq(index)` starts from 0

Comment: thanks for your reply. I however need it to work without the fadeOut-method,

Comment: you're welcome @MK01111000 .. you can remove the `fadeOut()` .. I updated my answer to let you know how its done ..